# Spring Auditing - Data too Long on createdBy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, auditing

Im implementing the auditing based on [1] but im not getting success with `@createdBy` and `@ModifiedBy`

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "entity")
public class myEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idMyEntity;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String nome;

    @CreatedBy
    private UserEntity userCreated;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private UserEntity userModified;

   ... getters and setters
```

}

And my AudityAware is:

```
public class AuditorAwareImp implements AuditorAware<UserEntity> {

    public UserEntity getCurrentAuditor() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return null;
        }


        System.out.println((UserEntity) authentication.getPrincipal());

        return ((UserEntity) authentication.getPrincipal());
    }
}
```

And my bean is:

```
@Bean
public AuditorAware<UserEntity> auditorAware() {
    return new AuditorAwareImp();
}
```

When i debug, i see the userEntity loaded as expected, but when jpa saves, it saves the .toString(), instead UserEntity `@Id`, which is not correct... giving me an error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'userCreated' at row 1
```

Why is it happening and how to fix?

[1] https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems was in the relationShip between the entities. When i did it, it solve my problem.

After  `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` i add `@OneToMany` according my relationship and worked as expected